# Can't generate results off of a while loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, while-loop

I am trying to find the intersection of two vectors v and g, and here's the code I wrote:

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4)
g <- c(3,4,5,99,0)

j = 1
new <- c()

for (i in 1:4){
  while (j < 5){
    if (v[i] == g[j])
      new <- c(new, v[i])
    j = j + 1
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've already created an empty vector named "new", since in R language a for loop doesn't store the results of running that code. But I still get no result in "new". I wonder why?

Comment: You could try `intersect(v,g)` which gives you the result you expect. for the why try to add `cat(i,j,'\n')`in the while loop

Comment: @Waldi, but I still appreciate your suggestion.  In fact, I think I shouldn't have used loops to perform such a task.

Comment: For the why, see the edit to my previous comment : j doesn't get reinitialized after each i, so that it only loops once

Comment: Just for avoidance of doubt: Is your question to find a way of doing this without a loop or are you asking for an explanation of why you get no results in your vector `new`?

Comment: @Peter I am asking for an explanation of why I got no results in new.

Comment: The why you are getting no result is after the first loop where i=1, j has a value of 5 thus when i increments it never executes the inner while loop.  You need to move the `j=1` after the `for` and before the `while`

Comment: @Dave2e, ohhh now I see it. And now I understand what Waldi meant by "reinitialized". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [Waldi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13513328/waldi) the problem is on the j reinitialization.

Try:

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4)
g <- c(3,4,5,99,0)

new <- c()

for (i in 1:4){
  j = 1  
  while (j < 5){
    print(paste('v=',v[i]))
    print(paste('g=',g[j]))
    print(v[i] == g[j])
    if (v[i] == g[j])
      new <- c(new, v[i])
    j = j + 1
  }
}
```